# neo4j performance issue when inserting nodes

Tags: neo4j

Inserting 2000 nodes consume 10000ms.  This is the code I am trying:

```
package org.demo.neo4j;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicRelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;

public class Main {

    private GraphDatabaseService neo = Noe4jUtils.getInstance();
    private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(4);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.insert();
    }

    private void insert() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                String refName = "REF-" + i;
                pool.execute(new InsertTask(refName, 100000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void insertRef(String refName, int num) {
        Node rootNode = neo.getReferenceNode();
        RelationshipType rt = DynamicRelationshipType.withName(refName);
        Relationship r = rootNode.getSingleRelationship(rt, Direction.OUTGOING);
        Node refNode;
        if (null == r) {
            refNode = createRef(rootNode, rt);
        } else {
            refNode = r.getOtherNode(rootNode);
        }
        int size = 2000;
        int cnt = num / size;
        if ((num % size) != 0) {
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            long l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Transaction tx = neo.beginTx();
            try {
                int tmpNum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    index++;
                    if (index > num) {
                        break;
                    }
                    tmpNum++;
                    createNode(refNode);
                }
                tx.success();
                System.out.println("insert " + tmpNum + " node.");
            } finally {
                tx.finish();
                l1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - l1;
                System.out.println("consume " + l1 + " ms.");
            }
        }
    }

    private Node createRef(Node node, RelationshipType rt) {
        Transaction tx = neo.beginTx();
        try {
            Node tmpNode = node.getGraphDatabase().createNode();
            node.createRelationshipTo(tmpNode, rt);
            tx.success();
            return tmpNode;
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }

    private Node createNode(Node node) {
        RelationshipType rt = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("LINK");
        Node tmpNode = node.getGraphDatabase().createNode();
        node.createRelationshipTo(tmpNode, rt);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            tmpNode.setProperty("key" + i, i);
        }
        return node;
    }

    class InsertTask implements Runnable {

        public InsertTask(String refName, int num) {
            this.refName = refName;
            this.num = num;
        }
        private String refName;
        private int num;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                insertRef(refName, num);
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of creating these small transactions? Each transaction in neo4j forces the logical log to disk, so basically all the time is spent waiting for your disk to flush. And as such multiple threads doesn't help all that much, on the contrary it can be slower. Try to group many operations together instead in each transaction and have one thread.

What is your use case by the way?

Answer (score -1):

Are you running this on an ext4 filesystem under Linux?

If you want to trade a little transaction safety for a 10-15x better write performance, try the barrier=0 option, as described here: http://structr.org/blog/neo4j-performance-on-ext4